# how to configure subversion with svn+https:// protocol?

Tags: svn, bower

I usually setup my svn servers using the ubuntu guide https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Subversion

But now at work we need to use bower to retrieve stuff on our svn repositories.

Bower can handle svn repos, based on their official webiste (http://bower.io/docs/api/#install); however they cite these protocols:

- svn+http://
- svn+https://

My repo is already configure to use only https://

I cannot find any information about how to configure these two protocols!

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of effort this is what I have understood.

there is no protocol `svn+http://` , nor `svn+https://` .

There is indeed `svn+ssh://` .

So, why Bower cites the first two options in its guide ?

Because if a repository starts with https they assume that it is GIT.

How to disambinguish between git and svn? well, at Bower, they have decided to put a "svn+" in front of it. So if you are pointing to `svn+https://yourRepo/beautiful_library` bower will try to read the package from `https://yourRepo/beautiful_library/tags/<version>`.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Python's package manager, `pip`, also [uses the convention](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#subversion).